# iPhone app opens in landscape mode on iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

Facts:

Developed a iPhone app which is rotatable in general but each single view is not rotatable at all. We just need the rotation feature in one explicit view, so we had to enable rotation in general.

Now, when one installs the app on iPad and opens it in landscape mode, the app shows up in landscape mode and you cannot rotate it back to portrait if you turn the iPad (which seems to be logically because rotation is not allowed in the views).

I do not experience that in the simulator :(

Anybody an idea what to do? Sorry for not including code...

Comment: Check your .plist and set all the orientation properties.

Comment: By default in iPhone app lauches in portrait but in iPad landscape and portrait splash screen is supported , might be because of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding "Supported interface orientations (iPad)" and ensure that "Portrait Bottom Home Button" is the first in the list.  Also, amend your root view controller so that it only shows up in Portrait.

Comment: This didn't work for me.. i added "Supported interface orientations (iPad)" and ensured that "Portrait Bottom Home Button" is the first in the list and i also added the function "shouldAutorotate" to my root view controller. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Mike M answer, I have this in mi RootViewController:

**Objective-C**

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

**Swift**

```
override func preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation() -> UIInterfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait
}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
}
```